# Java 8 Lambda Stream forEach with multiple statements

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am still in the process of learning Lambda, please excuse me If I am doing something wrong

```
final Long tempId = 12345L;
List<Entry> updatedEntries = new LinkedList<>();

for (Entry entry : entryList) {
    entry.setTempId(tempId);
    updatedEntries.add(entityManager.update(entry, entry.getId()));
}

//entryList.stream().forEach(entry -> entry.setTempId(tempId));
```

Seems like `forEach` can be executed for one statement only. It doesn't return updated stream or function to process further. I might have selected wrong one altogether.

Can someone guide me how to do this effectively?

One more question,

```
public void doSomething() throws Exception {
    for(Entry entry: entryList){
        if(entry.getA() == null){
            printA() throws Exception;
        }
        if(entry.getB() == null){
            printB() throws Exception;
        }
        if(entry.getC() == null){
            printC() throws Exception;
        }
    }
}
    //entryList.stream().filter(entry -> entry.getA() == null).forEach(entry -> printA()); something like this?
```

How do I convert this to Lambda expression?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**WARNING**

As mentioned in comments, **[Using peek() for production code is considered bad practice](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/rspec-3864/)**
The reasson is that "*According to its JavaDocs, the intermediate Stream operation java.util.Stream.peek() “exists mainly to support debugging” purposes.*"
As a consequence, this proposed solution SHOULD NOT be used.

---

Forgot to relate to the first code snippet. I wouldn't use `forEach` at all. Since you are collecting the elements of the `Stream` into a `List`, it would make more sense to end the `Stream` processing with `collect`. Then you would need `peek` in order to set the ID.

```
List<Entry> updatedEntries = 
    entryList.stream()
             .peek(e -> e.setTempId(tempId))
             .collect (Collectors.toList());
```

For the second snippet, `forEach` can execute multiple expressions, just like any lambda expression can :

```
entryList.forEach(entry -> {
  if(entry.getA() == null){
    printA();
  }
  if(entry.getB() == null){
    printB();
  }
  if(entry.getC() == null){
    printC();
  }
});
```

However (looking at your commented attempt), you can't use filter in this scenario, since you will only process some of the entries (for example, the entries for which `entry.getA() == null`) if you do.

Comment: isn't it peek() is recommended to use for debugging only. I think one should try map() instead

Comment: unfortunately we should not use peek... see https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3864

Answer (score 25):

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("A");
items.add("B");
items.add("C");
items.add("D");
items.add("E");

//lambda
//Output : A,B,C,D,E
items.forEach(item->System.out.println(item));

//Output : C
items.forEach(item->{
    System.out.println(item);
    System.out.println(item.toLowerCase());
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems like this is invalid syntax.  Isn't there an extra `}` at the end?

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to cram multiple operations into one stream/lambda.  Consider separating them into 2 statements  (using static import of `toList()`):

```
entryList.forEach(e->e.setTempId(tempId));

List<Entry> updatedEntries = entryList.stream()
  .map(e->entityManager.update(entry, entry.getId()))
  .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

In the first case alternatively to multiline `forEach` you can use the `peek` stream operation:

```
entryList.stream()
         .peek(entry -> entry.setTempId(tempId))
         .forEach(updatedEntries.add(entityManager.update(entry, entry.getId())));
```

In the second case I'd suggest to extract the loop body to the separate method and use method reference to call it via `forEach`. Even without lambdas it would make your code more clear as the loop body is independent algorithm which processes the single entry so it might be useful in other places as well and can be tested separately.

*Update after question editing*. if you have checked exceptions then you have two options: either change them to unchecked ones or don't use lambdas/streams at this piece of code at all.

Comment: what's the advantage of using `peek`. I haven't tried that function

Comment: @Reddy In this case I see no real advantage, since you can execute the `setTempId` call either in `peek` or in `forEach`, and the behavior will be similar. If, however, you don't use `forEach` at all, and use collect instead, in order to produce the output List (see my updated answer), you would need `peek` in order to call `setTempId`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `peek` [mainly should be used in debug purpose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-). Use `forEach` when applying side effects to your streamed data.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred approach is to concatenate `java.util.function.Consumer<?>` with `andThen(...)`.

Applied to your example, it can be written in:

```
entryList.stream()
  .forEach(
    ((Consumer<Entry>) entry -> entry.setTempId(tempId))
    .andThen(entry -> updatedEntries.add(entityManager.update(entry, entry.getId())))
  );
```

seen this way, is not that nice to read... but you can move the 2 consumers into local function variables and it would become as nice as:

```
Consumer<Entry> c1 = entry -> entry.setTempId(tempId);
Consumer<Entry> c2 = entry -> updatedEntries.add(entityManager.update(entry, entry.getId()));
entryList.stream().forEach(c1.andThen(c2));
```

---

##### Bonus

You may write your combinator of consumers like:

```
public static <T> Consumer<T> combine(Consumer<? super T>... consumers){
  return (T t) ->   Arrays.stream(consumers).forEach(c -> c.accept(t));
}
```

and it will allow to re-write the above example in:

```
entryList.stream()
  .forEach(combine(
    entry -> entry.setTempId(tempId),
    entry -> updatedEntries.add(entityManager.update(entry, entry.getId()))));
```

I wish `Consumer` class had a method to combine multiple consumers of the same type, maybe this `combine` already exists somewhere and I'm not aware of it, so I invite you to search