# Java stream "forEach" but not consuming stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Sometimes it would be handy do "something" (e.g. print) with every element in a stream in between steps of processing the stream, e.g. for debugging.

A simple example could look like this, unfortunately this does not work as `forEach` consumes the stream:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
list.add("four");

List<String> filteredList = 
        list.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("t"))
        .forEach(System.out::println)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Lambda Stream forEach with multiple statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130457/java-8-lambda-stream-foreach-with-multiple-statements)

Comment: @DidierL That duplicate is not really a good example since it _mutates_ the Stream element inside the `peek` operation.

Comment: @Tunaki I guess one that mutates will also fit when one does not actually need to mutate. The answer is really the same. I feel like all these `peek`-related questions are almost always the same.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are looking for the [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) operation:

> This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline

This method will execute the given action on all elements of the Stream pipeline as they are consumed. As such, it allows to take a [*peek*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peek) of the elements.

```
List<String> filteredList = 
    list.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("t"))
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi @Tunaki, I am very new to streams but any idea why following code doesnt print anything and also consumes the string?                                                                                                list.stream()
.filter(s -> s.startsWith("a"))
.peek(System.out::println);

Comment: Also any way to just print the stream without consuming it at all?

Comment: @Parth I think it's because the stream is not actually consumed and `peek` alone does not trigger that.